# Why does an open bounty make a question unclosable?

Tags: discussion, bounty, vote-to-close

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205537/what-video-streaming-audio-streaming-is-used-in-microsoft-hololens) has attracted at least 7 down-votes (1 mine) and no up-votes and in my opinion seems overly broad and at least a bit off-topic. Comments from other users have indicated as much too.

But it can't be closed because it has an open bounty which only expires in 6 days...

Surely having an open bounty shouldn't make a poor question immune from having the normal rules apply?

Comment: Probably because to be eligible for a bounty, it must be open for a period of time, and should have been closed in that window.

Comment: Sometimes questions that should be closed just get ignored ... Now its got some attention - still shouldn't make it immune.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, it's just that the system is built around what is good for StackOverflow.

Comment: Note that moderators have the ability to refund the bounty and close the question in situations like this. So it's not completely unclosable.